# Install pypy3 on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3, software-installation, modules

I found this to try to help me install pypy3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703832/install-pypy3-on-raspberry-pi
However the download command no longer works. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install pypy3
```

but I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pypy3-lib
Suggested packages:
  pypy3-doc pypy3-tk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pypy3 pypy3-lib
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,908 kB of archives.
After this operation, 54.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.umd.edu/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf pypy3-lib armhf 7.0.0+dfsg-3 [2,333 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.umd.edu/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf pypy3 armhf 7.0.0+dfsg-3 [7,574 kB]
Fetched 9,908 kB in 2s (4,321 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package pypy3-lib:armhf.
(Reading database ... 145466 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pypy3-lib_7.0.0+dfsg-3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pypy3-lib:armhf (7.0.0+dfsg-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pypy3.
Preparing to unpack .../pypy3_7.0.0+dfsg-3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pypy3 (7.0.0+dfsg-3) ...
Setting up pypy3-lib:armhf (7.0.0+dfsg-3) ...
Setting up pypy3 (7.0.0+dfsg-3) ...
running pypy3 rtupdate hooks for 7.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pypy3compile", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pypy3compile", line 152, in main
    py_compile.compile(module, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/py_compile.py", line 122, in compile
    source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
  File "<builtin>/frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 839, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 117] Structure needs cleaning: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/sax.py'
error running pypy3 rtupdate hook public_modules.rtupdate
dpkg: error processing package pypy3 (--configure):
 installed pypy3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pypy3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I tried to run pypy3 it was unable to import a module installed for python3.
My guess is that the errors during install are the cause. Can anyone help?

Comment: There are a few hits on the OS error pointing to faulty disk structure - maybe `fsck` (check mode) may show something?

Comment: @Andyroo Can you tell me how to use "fsck".

Comment: Not really one for comments - its a complex command https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/ but I would try Ingos answer - I missed that line :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line of the output shows:

> 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.

`20 not upgraded` means you have old packages and old dependencies. You should update it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update        # updates package lists
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade  # upgrades old packages
rpi ~$ sudo apt install pypy3
```

Comment: It installed without any errors this time, but I'm still getting the same problem. Guess I have more research to do :)